# Best way to alter font-size for different device resolutions in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova, font-size

I am developing a phonegap application for Android and I have designed the UI using jquery mobile. I want know what is the best way to alter the font-size of the text for different devices dynamically using css or javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Media queries are your friend!

In your CSS doc, use code similar to below (example is for the iphone 3-4 + Retina):

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) and (max-device-height: 480px) and (orientation:portrait) {
    p {
        font-size: 12px;
    }
}
```

You'll need to provide a few such queries to target the majority of devices (ipad, iphone, etc) but that should get you started!

Comment: Yes I have looked into that, but using that I have to write css for many resolutions so searching for some other way.

Comment: I think that's just a fact of life when developing responsive sites these days!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/). For instance, the nested CSS rules here will only apply to devices which are at least 500 pixels wide:

```
@media (min-width:500px) {
    #main {
        font-size: 15pt;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I have looked into that, but using that I have to write css for many resolutions so searching for some other way.